# JAXB - permGen error on Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, jaxb, permgen

I am getting the below error when running my deployed app. Going by the error, it seems JAXB is causing it. Please suggest.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:99)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:228)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:89)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:198)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:304)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:319)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:430)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:277)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1100)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:143)
    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:110)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
    javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:376)
    javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
    javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
    MyJava.GetUserProfile.user(GetUserProfile.java:87)
    com.myapp.struts.TokenDirected.execute(TokenDirected.java:81)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the size of your perm space first.  [This link](http://www.brokenbuild.com/blog/2006/08/04/java-jvm-gc-permgen-and-memory-options/) shows you how.

Monitor your memory usage with Visual GC to see how this helps.

If it doesn't, get rid of JAXB.  I shy away from it for exactly this reason.  Better to do your OXM by hand than rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem in Tomcat 5.5
JAXB will cause a lot of memory leaks for you, since it creates heaps of static variables in the server.

References:
http://blogs.oracle.com/fkieviet/entry/classloader_leaks_the_dreaded_java
http://blogs.oracle.com/fkieviet/entry/how_to_fix_the_dreaded

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to JAXB, but your Tomcat needs more memory from the JVM, so use something like

```
-Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:128m
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to JaxBContext. Every time you use a new context new classes are loaded. If you reuse your context everything will be fine.

duffyno is right :)